# nativeElement.value is incorrect in angular 7 directive

Tags: css, angular, angularjs-directive, angular-directive, angular7

I got incorrect value when I'm trying to select nativeElement.offsetwidth and nativeElement.offsetLeft. for both gotten value are the same and is different when I am consol.log full nativEelement.

[image]

[image]

same resut gives getComputedStyle: 
[image]

My Code looks like:

```
let tabs = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.tabs');
let selector = tabs.querySelector('.selector');
let activeItem = tabs.querySelector('.active');

console.log('activeItem.offsetWidth: ' + activeItem.offsetWidth);
console.log('activeItem.offsetLeft:' + activeItem.offsetLeft);
console.log('getComputedStyle(activeItem).width:' + getComputedStyle(activeItem).width);
console.log(getComputedStyle(activeItem));

console.log(activeItem);
```

Also, I have different values on firefox:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I think you missed the `nativeElement` part in your `console.log` statements.

Comment: Hi SiddAjmera. Can you tell where to set nativeElement part in ocnsole.log ? Thanks

Comment: I think here: `console.log('activeItem.offsetWidth: ' + activeItem.nativeElement.offsetWidth);` Not sure though. A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would really be helpful. You can use [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) to create one.

Comment: in which lifecylce all these happens?

Comment: @SiddAjmera that isn't related, nativeElement used and cached in tabs variable

Comment: Hi, good question It was happening in NgOnInit and inside NgAfterInit it works but only in chrome. firefox still the same results. What do you think about firefox?Thanks

Comment: You should show the relevant template markup in the question.

Comment: Hi connorsFan, I will try. Before if you have some advice about differecces between firefox and chrome please tell. Thanks